# ¿Cuándo y cómo pasó "guiri" a designar a un turista extranjero?

Tags: etimología, historia, españa, sustantivos

Por curiosidad me da por buscar la etimología de *[guiri](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JrGGH0A)*, y me encuentro con que viene del vasco *guiristino* 'cristino', término que según el DLE significa:

> En las guerras civiles del siglo XIX, partidario de la reina Cristina. Era usado también para designar a los liberales, y en especial a los soldados del Gobierno.

Esta acepción cuadra con la etimología, pero en algún momento pasó a usarse, hoy en día mayoritariamente diría yo, para referirse coloquialmente a los turistas extranjeros, como indica su tercera acepción.

¿Cuándo y cómo se produjo este cambio? Bonus: ¿se usa esta voz con el mismo significado en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: The DLE first records the `com. vulg. Extranjero, turista` definition in its 1989 edition (source: NTLLE).

Comment: Es una de las pocas palabras españolas que no sólo no se usan de este lado, sino que tampoco nos suenan a nada. :)

Comment: Nunca he oído llamar "guiri" a los turistas sudamericanos que vienen a España. En mi opinión guiri implica anglosajón, o como mínimo turista extranjero _que no habla español_, y como consecuencia de ello no se entera de lo que sucede a su alrededor.

Comment: Hablan de ello: [Liberal, guardia civil, turista... Todos los significados que ha tenido la palabra guiri](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2019/04/10/articulo/1554900648_602019.html)

Answer (score 5):

Como @ukemi y @Diego analizan la etimología de "guiri" en su respuesta, afrontemos la aparición de la nueva acepción:

- En Google Books he encontrado un breve fragmento de la [**"Balada de Juan Campos"**](https://books.google.es/books?id=BOKyAAAAIAAJ&q=%22guiri%22), de Gonzalo Torrente Malvido (**1964**) en el que aparece la palabra **guiri** referida a una mujer, un uso diferente de los recogidos hasta ese momento (guardia civil o soldado):

  > "... pues **la guiri** había dejado el cesto abierto; el autobús iba casi vacío..."
- En la canción "Pepe Rodríguez, el de la barba en flor", Pablo Guerrero (**1972**) canta ([**1**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyoPpGWWBJE)):

  > ... Arco de Cuchilleros baja con tal primor
  >   que **extranjeras y "guiris"** le demandan amor.
  >   ...
  >   Pepe Rodríguez, el de la barba en flor,
  >   lleva a sus **"guiris"** a un piso coquetón,
  >   ...

  Lo que refleja que ya en esos años era una palabra conocida y que existe alguna diferencia entre **extranjera** y **guiri**.

- Como señala @ukemi en un comentario, aparece oficialmente recogido por primera vez en 1989, en el diccionario manual de la RAE.

- En [*Moros, sudacas y guiris*, una forma de contemplar la diversidad humana en Barcelona](http://www.ub.edu/geocrit/sn-94-58.htm) de Nadja Monnet (2001) se profundiza en la diferencia terminológica para denominar a distintos extranjeros. Indica que **guiri** se utiliza para referirse a únicamente a **determinado tipo de extranjeros** y que la aparición y difusión del término se produjo en los años 1960 - 1980:

  > ... los "guiris" son "extranjeros", en su sentido restringido de "gente que vienen a gastar dinero y a pasárselo bien. ... el arquetipo del "guiri" es el playero, el visitante alto, rubio en búsqueda de sol... Por lo tanto es ante todo "el extranjero germánico"...
  >   ... la palabra, en su sentido más común hoy en día, está vinculada con el desarrollo económico de España en las **décadas 1960-1970**, la llegada del turismo y la decadencia del régimen de Franco.
- En [¿Quiénes son los guiris?](https://cafebabel.com/es/article/quienes-son-los-guiris-5ae00a42f723b35a145e6164/) se incide en el cambio de la acepción moderna y en el momento de aparición:

  > Aunque, en un principio, identificábamos como guiris a los turistas del norte de Europa, hoy parece que el guiri es todo aquel visitante que pone los pies en nuestras costas y ciudades más emblemáticas. De hecho, según la Real Academia Española, la palabra "guiri" significa, en español coloquial, "turista extranjero", sin distinción.
  >   
  >    Se cree que el término fue recuperado en la España de los años 60, con la forma abreviada "guiri", cuando la mentalidad liberal de los extranjeros que visitaban el país en los primeros años de nuestra recuperación económica, chocaba con la ideología tradicional del Franquismo.
  >   Aunque también hay quien opina que en la evolución de esta palabra ha influido el término "**guirigay**", el alboroto que se forma como consecuencia de un lenguaje incomprensible y que también estaría relacionado con la lengua que hablan los extranjeros.

En conclusión:

Este uso de **guiri**  aparece documentado desde al menos **1964** y ha evolucionado desde el inicial concepto *turista de piel pálida que se quema con el sol* a *cualquier turista extranjero*.

Sobre cómo se produjo el cambio, hay las dos hipótesis citadas en [¿Quiénes son los guiris?](https://cafebabel.com/es/article/quienes-son-los-guiris-5ae00a42f723b35a145e6164/) que no parecen ser excluyentes: recuperación en los años 60 de la palabra con el sentido de *liberal* y aplicándola a los turistas por su mentalidad liberal (en comparación con la general de España de esos años), o adaptación/modificación del ***guirigay*** de los turistas extranjeros.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain how [*guiri*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guiri) would have come to mean "[European] tourist" after its pre-established progression of meanings:

- [Cristinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlist_Wars)

  - liberals

    - government soldiers

      - Guardia Civil & Policía Armada

However, Juan Goytisolo proposes an alternative etymology of the secondary meaning ("European tourist") with a clearer semantic link:

> <sup>6</sup> "El *guiur* o infiel —nombre derivado del árabe *câfir*, del que procede nuestro 'cafre' y que, tras originar en el Maghreb dominado antaño por los otomanos el actual *gauri* (plural, *guâra*) con el que se designa hoy de un modo un tanto peyorativo a los europeos, aterrizará finalmente entre nosotros en forma de neologismo caló *guiri*—" (Goytisolo 1989: 62).
>
> - [*Pesquisas en la obra tardía de Juan Goytisolo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=zOEVlJWy6moC&q=guiri#v=snippet&q=guiri&f=false), Brigitte Adriaensen, Marco Kunz (p.51, 66)

Comment: Me llama mucho la atención está posible etimología. Gracias por compartirlo.

Answer (score 2):

En [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?guiri) señalan que según tanto Corominas como el DRAE (como apuntas),

> la palabra `guiri` que actualmente designa en lenguaje coloquial **de España - no parece emplearse en América-**  <sub>(afirmación que parecen corroborar los comentarios a la pregunta)</sub> a los turistas extranjeros

Indican el origen a la referencia de *cristinos* (por la reina Cristina) dirigido hacia los soldados del gobierno liberal por parte de los sublevados carlistas. En boca de carlistas vascoparlantes "cristinos" sonaría "guiristinos" (del mismo modo que *cruze* del latín da *gurutze* en vasco). Además parece que en vasco ya existía la palabra "guiristino" con el significado de "cristiano".

Luego añaden

> De significar soldados que combatían a los carlistas la voz pasaría a designar a cualquier uniformado, soldado o guardia civil. En la obra de Pérez Galdós "Zumalacárregui" **(1898)** aparece repetidamente la voz *guiri*  para denominar por parte de los carlistas a los soldados gubernamentales que les combatían. En su boca, claro, la palabra sonaba muy despectiva. En un pasaje incluso se comenta "que a los de la Guardia se les llamó *guiris*  porque llevaban en su gorra las letras G.R.I. (Guardia Real de Infantería)". **Aquí tenemos otra propuesta etimológica poco creíble, en nuestra opinión** [por etimologías de Chile]. En otra ocasión, en otro libro de Galdós, "De Cartago a Sagunto" **1911** se lee: "tan pronto invadían la posada los oficiales *carcas* (los carlistas) como los *guiris*" que con tal nombre eran conocidos en Navarra los liberales.

Sobre la evolución para designar a un turista extranjero, etimologías de Chile conjetura:

> Ahora bien, **en el cambio del significado actual hacia extranjero podría, eventualmente, haber influido la fonética del vocablo, asociado tal vez a *guirigay***  o a un lenguaje incomprensible. Es de observar, por otra parte, que en el lenguaje castellano actual, en registros muy coloquiales se utiliza el término *guripa*  señalando a uniformados, 'guardias, policías, soldados, o individuo de cuidado' que recuerdan algunos usos de la voz *guiri*. Los etimólogos suelen decir que *guripa*  viene de un origen caló, pero la cuestión no está clara.

Aparte de esas notas sobre el origen, respaldadas por el DRAE y Corominas, una entrada adicional de etimologías de Chile propone (sin ningún respaldo) que *guiri* puede ser una corrupción de *girls*, ya que en temporada de verano (cuando más turistas hay) se intenta ligar con las *girls*, y de una corrupción en la pronunciación pasó a *guiri* y de ahí a designar no solo a las chicas sino a todos los extranjeros.

Esta versión me parece menos creíble, pero merecía señalarse.

Answer (score 1):

**Cuestión:** " Guiri Como Turista"

---

Realmente me hace gracia la cuestión. Es algo que hace años, antes incluso que existiera internet y las nuevas tecnologías, donde lo que voy a contar ya se puede comprobar con más facilidad, ya hablaba con mis amigos de este curioso tema, creyendo aquellos que la palabra "guiri" era originaria Española en su versión "turista", sin saber la razón de la misma ó el motivo que había empujado a alguien hacia una voz, en su composición, un tanto "extraña" para referirse genéricamente a los viajeros extranjeros. Las conversaciones transcurrían entre interpretaciones personales y muchas otras posibles etimologías transcritas aquí ya en otras respuestas o aquella otra que la derivaba supuestamente, no se como, de la palabra "gamba".

En aquellas conversaciones intentaba aclarar que "GIRIS", era una voz tomada del idioma Turco "**Giriş**", terminada en "Ş" con cedilla, que significa, entre otras cosas,  "entrada" y que nosotros la habíamos recogido y convertido en "guiris", pues el sonido en Turco es el mismo que pronunciamos y que en nuestro caso, sin embargo, podríamos incurrir en error al leer "*giris*", lease "*jiris*", con el mismo sonido que utilizamos en "geranio", lease "*jeranio*", de ahí el sonido "**Gui**-ri".

La mejor versión hallada y contrastada con Españoles que en épocas tempranas del "boom turístico", habían viajado a Turquía, era que los "viajeros extranjeros", a la línea de la cola, incluidos los Españoles, se convirtieron en "guiris", cuando en fila, aguardaban a la "entrada" de cualquier evento, exhibición, monumentos, museo, mezquita.... en espera de entrar, pues por lo general, la hilera estaba exclusivamente compuesta por viajeros extranjeros, que pacientemente permanecían en columna para acceder a los distintos puntos, piénsese, que el término "turista", aún, no era de uso, ni común. Así pues, los que esperaban a la "entrada" en cola, eran las personas Giriş, es decir, personas que esperan o están para entrar.

---

[image]

---

Es esta relación de "*Giriş*" como "entrada en", en este caso, en un país, la que hemos utilizado e importado como correspondencia, *a la de un viajero extranjero que entra*, como sinónimo inicial de "turista", quizás porque algunos Españoles en su momento, como "Guiris" en Turquía, tuvieron que estar  en cola para entrar y cuando volvieron, utilizaron el mismo término para los extranjeros, de aquellos primeros años, que venían y se agolpaban en línea o en tumulto para entrar a cualquier evento, extendiéndose la expresión en general para "extranjeros que entran en el país".

En este sentido, es curioso el "*verbo entrar*" en Turco, "fiil *gir*". Cuando dices "tu entras" es "*giriş*" yaptın, aunque el verbo también posee otras acepciones como ingreso, recepción, aceptar, antesala, preludio...así se puede encontrar "*Giriş*" en un cajero, en el hotel, en el examen de ingreso, en el aeropuerto, en un museo, en una mezquita...

En mi opinión, como he comentado antes, tuvo que ser algún avezado grupo de "viajeros" u hombres de negocios Españoles acostumbrados a viajar los que una vez de vuelta utilizaron la expresión "guiri o giri" para referirse a los "viajeros", hoy turistas, que como ellos, esperaban en algún sitio para entrar.

En este sentido, el término lentamente se extendió, prolifero y se amplificó también para aquellos extranjeros que "entraban" en España desde otros países, ya que la voz "turista" y "turismo" tiene una evolución lenta y tardía en el diccionario y aún hoy se encuentra sujeta a discrepancias etimológicas entre autores, que la retrasan hasta los años 50' del siglo XX, (*Empresa Nacional de Turismo, Entursa, empresa pública Española dedicada al sector de la hostelería, creada en 1963* ), ya que el concepto primario de "tour" (1772), "touriste" (1873), lo aleja mucho del actual fenómeno económico-cultural que hemos desarrollado, y sobre la visión del "turismo" y del "turista" en particular que hoy existe.

Comment: https://www.vigoempresa.com/el-periodistico-origen-de-la-palabra-guiri/

Comment: El artículo que comentas me ha hecho después de tantos años reflexionar sobre el origen del término, no por la noticia en sí a la que haces mención, que no creo que sea cierta, pues el País fue fundado el 4 de mayo de 1976 y la primera reseña en la que aparece la palabra "guiri" es el 19 DIC 1978, https://elpais.com/diario/1978/12/19/madrid/282918262_850215.html, donde detienen a un tal, "Alberto López el Guiri ". Así, no creo que en tan corto plazo el término se expandiera tanto como para que un chaval de 17 años lo recibiera como apodo. Editare la respuesta para añadir otra visión Gracias