# ¿Cómo adquirió "polaco" su acepción como calificativo para un partido político?

Tags: etimología, españa, lenguaje-peyorativo

En una pregunta reciente, [¿Cuándo y cómo pasó “guiri” a designar a un turista extranjero?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28191/5481) aprendimos que

> guiri viene del vasco *guiristino* 'cristino', término que según el DLE fue acuñado en las guerras civiles del siglo XIX, referido a los partidarios de la reina Cristina. Era usado también para designar a los liberales, y en especial a los soldados del Gobierno.

Cosa curiosa, esta pregunta, que estaba en mi lista de cosas para preguntar el el *stack*, me recordó a otra similar que tengo pendiente acerca de una de las acepciones de [polaco](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TVA82VC) en el DRAE

> 4. adj. Dicho de un partido político: Que gobernó en España desde 1850 a 1854. U. t. c. s.

En su momento recuerdo haber investigado esta pregunta, sin encontrar nada satisfactorio. Fue hace bastante tiempo, así que no recuerdo con seguridad por dónde busqué.

Posiblemente alguien con mejores conocimientos que los míos sobre la historia de España, sepa mejor dónde buscar para encontrar un buena explicación sobre la etimología de esta acepción.

Comment: Gracias por el apunte. Ese detalle no se me pasa por alto, aunque esa acepción no esté recogida en el DRAE. Entre tú y yo (ahora que no nos oye nadie), una de las razones por las que no hice esta pregunta (y otras) era por cómo estaba el _temita_ en Cataluña. Como veo que la cosa va _pa'largo_, empezaré a hacer algunas de estas preguntas que en su momento pensé que podrían darse a ser mal recibidas. No creo que la acepción que mencionas esté directamente relacionada con esta pregunta, así que haré una pregunta propia para ella.

Comment: Me parece extraño que la RAE no reconoce su uso peyorativo actual. Es bastante común, hasta el título (satírico) de [*Polònia*](https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polònia_(programa)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... the term "polacos" emerged against an entirely different background in the mid-1850s; the name was applied to a faction of [Partido Moderado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderate_Party_(Spain)). The grouping was led by [Luis José Sartorius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Jos%C3%A9_Sartorius,_1st_Count_of_San_Luis), a politician erroneously supposed to be of Polish origin.<sup>4</sup>
>
> ...
>
> <sup>4. Barbara Obtułowicz, *Luis Jose Sartotius, hrabia de San Luip. Polak, który nie był Polakiem*, Kraków 2012
>
>   ("Luís José Sartorius, conde de San Luís: leyenda y realidad"), [in:] *Intinerarios* 15 (2012), pp. 279-303</sup>
>
> - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaco_(slur)#Antecedents

Comment: Entonces, cuando el DRAE dice "Dicho de *un* partido político" se refiere a este en particular (Partido Moderado)? O hay más de un partido (o facción del mismo) que reciba este calificativo?

Comment: @Diego en las entradas de las ediciones del DLE hasta 2001, dicen `Del partido político...` `El partido político...` / `Partido político...`. No sé por qué en la versión en línea se formula menos claramente.

Comment: Pues no sería la primera vez que conseguimos que actualicen una entrada del diccionario, no? Ya ni me acuerdo quién fue ni con qué pregunta (era la de las entradas cíclicas en el diccionario?). Tendré que preguntar en meta.

Comment: @Diego la RAE nos ha admitido a trámite algunas de nuestras sugerencias, pero creo que a día de hoy ninguna se ha hecho efectiva.