# ¿Cómo se puede hacer formalmente una petición a la RAE para actualizar una entrada del diccionario?

Tags: definiciones, dle, rae, diccionarios

En la respuesta a una pregunta reciente ([¿Cómo adquirió “polaco” su acepción como calificativo para un partido político?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28273/5481)) discutíamos en los comentarios la completitud o exactitud de la entrada en el diccionario. [Ukemi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/18348/ukemi), que respondió a la pregunta, aclaraba mediante comentario que

> en las entradas de las ediciones del DLE hasta 2001, [la definición queda más clara] No sé por qué *en la versión en línea se formula menos claramente*

y yo respondía preguntando si no deberíamos proponer que se actualizase esa entrada. [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie), quien a veces se tuitea con Pérez-Reverte, me recordaba que

> la RAE nos ha admitido a trámite algunas de nuestras sugerencias, pero creo que a día de hoy ninguna se ha hecho efectiva.

Uno de los casos que yo recuerdo fue [¿Deben las definiciones del DLE ser autosuficientes?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24459/5481), en la que Charlie, a través de Twitter, contactó a la RAE acerca de la duda expresada en la pregunta de [Blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14069/blonfu).

Entiendo que Twitter, donde la RAE tiene presencia y resuelve consultas de distinta índole, es uno de los canales para ponerse en contacto con la RAE. Supongo que es el método lógico para ciertas "peticiones", como cuando un comentario escala hasta hacer *presión social* para exigir el cambio (cosa que vimos tangencialmente en [¿Alguna vez ha la RAE eliminado/cambiado la definición de una palabra por petición?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27454/5481)), y que puede ser el más cómodo y rápido para el usuario, pero no sé si es el preferido o considerado más correcto y formal por parte de la RAE.

Así que, para que conste en acta (y sea consultable en el stack en el futuro), y sepamos cuál es la forma más correcta y que puede darnos mejores opciones de lograr que nuestra petición sea atendida, ¿Cómo se puede (o debe) hacer formalmente una petición a la RAE para actualizar una entrada del diccionario?

Comment: Antes había un formulario donde podrías hacer sugerencias para nuevas entradas o acepciones.  Ahora no lo encuentro en el sitio (pero sé que si no existe, existía antes, porque lo usé para recomendar la inclusión de la palabra **aurisecular** que, de hecho, todavía no queda registrada)

Comment: Podría ser interesante incluir en la respuesta algo más sobre el **proceso** en sí (no creo que merezca la pena hacer una pregunta diferente para ello), para saber por ejemplo cuánto pueden tardar en responderte, revisar la petición, qué ocurre si la aceptan, etc. Tu guifa mandaste esa petición/sugerencia hace mucho?

Comment: fue hace años jaja.  Cada academia propone nuevas palabras para la reunión de ASALE (que es cada tres años).  A mi entender es cuando normalmente aprueban nuevas entradas o cambios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El canal oficial para este tipo de peticiones es el siguiente:

## [**Formulario de propuestas al DLE**](http://www.rae.es/formulario/unidrae)

Descripción que la propia Academia hace de este canal:

> **Formulario de propuestas al DLE**
>
> La Unidad Interactiva del Diccionario (UNIDRAE) se creó en 2011 para recibir las propuestas y sugerencias externas relacionadas con el *Diccionario de la lengua española*.
>
> Las comunicaciones que se remitan a este servicio han de ceñirse exclusivamente a artículos del *Diccionario*.
>   En la casilla «Palabra» se debe escribir la voz sobre la que se va a hacer el comentario.
>   Las propuestas que se refieran a la inclusión en el Diccionario de un nuevo término o expresión han de acompañarse tanto de su significado como de documentación que avale su uso. **El diccionario académico no recoge voces inexistentes** en la lengua escrita **ni palabras de creación personal esporádica**. El resto de las propuestas han de estar igualmente argumentadas y justificadas.
>
> La UNIDRAE responde acusando recibo inmediato de la llegada de la propuesta, que será objeto de un estudio exhaustivo posterior.

Para poder enviar el formulario es obligatorio proporcionar los siguientes datos personales:

- Nombre y apellidos
- Correo electrónico
- Dirección de contacto
- Lugar de residencia
- País de origen

Además de, por supuesto, la palabra en cuestión y la explicación de la propuesta, bien argumentada.
El formulario permite adjuntar ficheros a la propuesta, con las siguientes restricciones:

- Los archivos deben ser menores de 8 MB.
- Tipos de archivo permitidos: `gif jpg png bmp eps tif pict psd txt rtf html odf pdf doc docx ppt pptx xls xlsx xml`.

Por último, es necesario aceptar (¡cómo no!) la [política de privacidad de la RAE](http://www.rae.es/info/aviso-legal).

---

*Como experiencia personal, comentar que yo he utilizado el formulario en un par de ocasiones —la última, para pedir la inclusión de [puaj](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23928/13628)— y no me consta que en ninguna de ellas la RAE me respondiera* «acusando recibo inmediato de la llegada de la propuesta»*; de hecho no me respondieron en absoluto. También [seguimos esperando a que nos respondan](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21035/13628) a otra consulta hecha por canal oficial, en este caso al Departamento de Publicaciones a través del [formulario de contacto](http://www.rae.es/formulario/contacto).*

Comment: El canal que casi siempre responden es el [twiiter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma).